# Verify solution of system of first order ODE

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I am given a solution $v_1$(t)=$-e^{t/2}cost$ for a system of first order ODE and I am asked to verify this solution can solves the linear second order ODE in terms of $y_1$(t)

Here is the matrix ODE
[![enter image description]
After get $y_2$(t), I copy the output of y2[t] and use `D` to take its derivative`

```
D[(-2 y1[t] + y1[t] - 2 Derivative[1][y1][t])/(
 2 + 3 Cos[t] Sin[t]), t]
```

Next, I equate $y_2'$(t) to the second component of the coefficient matrix (second row of the matrix), and *finally*, i obtained second ODE in terms of $y_1$(t), $y_1'$(t) and $y_1''$(t) **(*)**

```
{-(((3 Cos[t]^2 - 3 Sin[t]^2) (-2 y1[t] + 3 Cos[t]^2 y1[t] - 
    2 Derivative[1][y1][t]))/(2 + 3 Cos[t] Sin[t])^2) + (-6 Cos[
   t] Sin[t] y1[t] - 2 Derivative[1][y1][t] + 
 3 Cos[t]^2 Derivative[1][y1][t] - 2 (Prime])[t]}]
```

**Summary**

Sorry if it is hard to follow, it is quite messy to right details but basically i have the matrix ode and i used mathematica to rearrange the equation and then substitution so that finally i get a single second ODE with only $y_1$(t) $y_1’$(t) and $y_1’’$(t). Then i plug in the solution i have into this equation and verify that it is 0. But i can’t get it and i am not sure if it is due to systax error or any possible mistakes i could get during computing with mathematica.

Is there any syntax errors or any mistakes I have made throughout the process?
Any help please :):). Thank you very much

Comment: `I am given a solution for a system of first order ODE` Where is the solution you are given? I do not see it? is it the v1 there? Your question is a little hard to follow.

Comment: @Nasser Sorry for that i have edited the post little bit. Could you try to help me with that? Thanks so much :):)

Comment: I don't think $y_1(t)=e^{-t/2} \cos (t)$ is a solution; and Mathematica is telling you so.

Comment: @ulvi it is $-e^{t/2}cos(t)$.The question i had is verify that $v_1$(t) can solve the second ODE i have just found in terms of $y_1$(t).... so it should be 0 when i plug the solution in :(

Comment: @tabitha96 It is not nice, towards someone who answered, to delete a topic without notice.

Comment: Let's ask @Nasser.

Comment: `please allow me to delete so that i would update another one`  well, you could always either accept the answer and then make new question, or do not accept the answer, and make new question. But deleting a question once an answer is there, means the answer posted can no longer be seen, and it was waste to time.  How would you feel if you spend long time writing an answer, only to have it removed by someone else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you gives does not satisfy the ODE?

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
y_{1}^{\prime}\\
y_{2}^{\prime}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
y_{1}\\
y_{2}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Hence 
\begin{align*}
y_{1}^{\prime}  & =a_{11}y_{1}+a_{12}y_{2}\\
y_{2}^{\prime}  & =a_{21}y_{1}+a_{22}y_{2}
\end{align*}

But $y_{1}=y$ and $y_{2}=y^{\prime}$, therefore the above becomes

\begin{align*}
y_{1}^{\prime}  & =a_{11}y+a_{12}y^{\prime}\\
y_{2}^{\prime}  & =a_{21}y+a_{22}y^{\prime}
\end{align*}

And also $y_{1}^{\prime}=y^{\prime},y_{2}^{\prime}=y^{\prime\prime}$,
therefore the above becomes

\begin{align*}
y^{\prime}  & =a_{11}y+a_{12}y^{\prime}\\
y^{\prime\prime}  & =a_{21}y+a_{22}y^{\prime}
\end{align*}

Solving for $y^{\prime}$ from first equation above gives $y^{\prime}
=\frac{a_{11}y}{1-a_{12}}$. Substituting this in the second equation gives

\begin{align*}
y^{\prime\prime}=a_{21}y+a_{22}\frac{a_{11}y}{\left(  1-a_{12}\right)  }
\end{align*}

Or

\begin{align*}
y^{\prime\prime}=\left(  a_{21}+a_{22}\frac{a_{11}}{1-a_{12}}\right)  y
\end{align*}

To verify that $v\left(  t\right)  =-e^{\frac{t}{2}}\cos\left(  t\right)  $ is
a solution, plugin into the above and see if it satisfies it.

```
ClearAll[y,t,v]
a={{-1+3/2Cos[t]^2,1-3/2 Sin[t]Cos[t]},
  {-1-3/2 Sin[t]Cos[t],-1+3/2 Sin[t]^2}};
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ode=y''[t]==(a[[2,1]] +a[[2,2]] a[[1,1]] /(1-a[[1,2]]))y[t];
ode=Simplify[ode]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
v[t_]:=-Exp[t/2] Cos[t];
ode/.{y[t]->v[t],y''[t]->v''[t]}//Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It does not satisfy it. If it did, we'll get `True` at the end.

Are you sure `-Exp[t/2] Cos[t]` is supposed to be a solution?